# Regular expression for folder path validation in javscript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate the folder path in javascript, which should contain the workspace(any string is acceptable) as a folder

```
"/homes/nb/workspace3/sdddsdd".match(/^\/(.*)\/workspace(.*)$/g)
```

Below should pass when workspace with any integer or characters is present

```
/homes/suresh/workspace3
/homes/nb/workspace
/volume/kiran/workspace123
/homes/nb/workspace3233
/homes/nb/workspace123
/homes/nb/workspace012
/volume/kiran/workspace
```

below case, it should fail that means it should not contain a further folder name after a workspace

```
/volume/kiran/workspace123/hbdhdhjs
/volume/kiran/workspace/hbdhdhjs
/homes/nb/workspace012/dsdsd
```

Comment: `after workspace` After what workspace, can you be more specific ?

Comment: @Maxt8r /volume/kiran/workspace(here it can contain integer or any character) after this it should not contain a slash and any other folder name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part should match

`/workspace[^\/]*$/`

see  https://regex101.com/r/Ti950e/1

Note that you don't need to match before `workspace` because
it is simply the target string.

If you want to allow a trailing `/` only at the end, use this instead

`/workspace[^\/]*\/?$/`

see https://regex101.com/r/veXzXm/1